# Attempted to read or write protected memory error. Suggestions please

Tags: c#, multithreading

After two months of trying to track down this random problem, I’m going to ask for some help in the hope that someone may see what I am missing or at least point me in the right direction.  I have gone over many different posts from here and other websites that deal with the same error and tried a number of suggested fixes but none seem to be working.

My program is a windows service (because it needs to be able to run on machines without a user logged in) that runs out of the console when running in dev environment.  It sits in-between a third-party program and a piece of hardware that is connected to the PC via a serial port.  My program uses an Eltima virtual null modem com port pair to connect to the existing program and intercept messages passing between it and the hardware, which is connected to a real com port.  Certain messages between the two, when detected, will trigger a JSON message to be sent through PubNub to a mobile device on a specific PubNub channel.

When the third-party program is not running, the service will continue to check the hardware for messages every second.  Any important messages are stored in a database until the next time the other program connects at which point they will be sent on to it.  The error has occurred when the third party program is not running (has not connected at all) and I am not getting any data on the virtual com port.

I also have a WCF servicehost duplex channel set up to communicate to another app that I wrote, which resides in the tray.  This app is used for changing configurations and setups for the service, and to display pop up messages from the tray when certain conditions are present.  Note that when the error happens that the tray app has not ever been connected to the service.  The host is just waiting for a connection.

The error happens anywhere from within a few seconds of the program starting up and only having issued one or two requests for data from the hardware, to several days after starting and thousands of requests.  When it happens, my code is not in the middle of executing any methods.  At least, it doesn’t appear to be.  I’ve placed debug statements at the beginning of each code block, and at all exit points and the output from that seems to show that the error happens outside of my code blocks.

I am using version 4.5.2 of the framework.

Not using any third party `dlls` or other unmanaged code.  No OCX's or COM objects.

All my timers that I use are `System.Timers.Timer` type.  `Autoreset` is set to `false` and I manually restart them when I’m sure that everything has been taken care of.  There’s only one timer running when the error happens.

PubNub has been initialized and subscribed successfully to a channel (to listen for mobile device connection) when I am getting the error.

Some items that I have tried are:

1: Setting the build target to `x86`.

2: Setting `legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy` to `true` in the `app.cofig` file.

3: Setting `legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy` to `true` in the `app.cofig` file.

4: Adding a trace to my WCF service to see if it has any errors that show up before the Access Violation and I don’t see any.

5: All my collections and dictionaries that I use are of the Concurrent type.

6: Tried putting [`HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`] on each code block.

7: Added an `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException UnhandledExceptionEventHandler`.

8: Unchecked “Suppress JIT optimization”.

9: Set `UseSynchronizationContext = false` in `ServiceBehavior` attributes.

And probably some others that I have forgotten about in my efforts.

From WinDbg, and one of my minidumps.  (I assume that since I’m building for x86, that I have to use the 32 bit version of WinDbg, which I am.  I also have the 64 bit and tried that, but its results pointed me at a line in a file that does not have any code on it.)

The Managed Call Stack:

```
062ff6a8 7235a5e4 System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\overlapped.cs @ 117]

062ff7a4 7341eb16 [GCFrame: 062ff7a4] 

062ff8a8 7341eb16 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 062ff8a8]
```

The unmanaged Call Stack on the faulting thread:

```
062feb48 768815ce ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15

062febb4 770d1194 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98

062febcc 7354008b kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75

062febfc 735400d2 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x33

062fec4c 73540057 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a

062fec84 73540152 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152

062fec94 71f5cb48 clr!CLREventBase::Wait+0x1a

WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.

00000000 00000000 WRusr!SynProc+0xee68


Thread processor time shows faulting thread 13 is not in a runaway:

0:013> !runaway

 User Mode Time

  Thread       Time

   6:1670      0 days 0:00:11.965

  18:44e0      0 days 0:00:00.280

  13:16dc      0 days 0:00:00.140

   2:2500      0 days 0:00:00.093

   0:43c0      0 days 0:00:00.046
```

I’ve put a screenshot of the code from `overlapped.cs` below.  I got the file from Microsoft’s repository.

[image: overlapped.cs]

I also have a screenshot of my parallel stacks.  The one thread in bold with the yellow pointer is the error.  Also shown is the thread for the PubNub subscription, and my 2 serial ports waiting for com events.

[image: Parallel Call Stack]

So, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post "screenshots of code", it isn't helpful as we can't copy/paste and it is difficult to read in the context of the question.

Comment: Don't post Microsoft's code either. Post *your* code and the full exception including its call stack. You can get this with `Exception.ToString()`. Log exceptions in your application, don't expect event viewer to show such detail

Comment: You mention null modems and drivers - are you sure they are thread safe? What does your code do when the exception occurs? Are you using unsafe buffers? Interop? P/Invoke? If you use the wrong buffer size in an IO operation, yes, the CLR will throw when it exceeds the buffer limits but it's *your* code that caused the bug, not CLR.

Comment: If you call a native API that isn't thread-safe from multiple threads you can easily end up writing one thread's response on another thread's buffer.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting errors.  The null modem I mentioned is simply a virtual com port that is accessed via the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort object.  When the error happens, the virtual com port is just sitting there waiting for a connection from the 3rd party program.  The second com port, which is a real 9 pin port on the machine, is sending and receiving data.

Comment: I am not calling any native API's or doing any Interop or P/Invoke.  What is my code doing when the error occurs?  It's just sitting there waiting for a SerialDataReceived event from the com port.

Comment: I posted the MS code because that's where WinDbg says the error is happening.

Comment: I made a slight modification to my code with how the UnhandledException event gets handled.  I had originally had it in my service thread but I moved it to the void Main of program.cs and it catches the error there now like I had hoped.  Using the parallel thread display I was able to select my main thread and switch to it and inspect all of the local variables for the program.  Absolutely everything looks exactly like it should.  I don't have any nulls or disposed objects where I shouldn't have them.  No bytes waiting in the serial port buffer or anything.  So now I'm even more at a loss.